# CLI Utility to see the http requests that'll be made by a command

Tags: networking, command-line, wireshark

I have a script which invokes some library code that makes some HTTP and HTTPS requests, let's call it `script.sh`

Is there a command which would look like `some-wireshark-type-utility ./script.sh` and it would output the interceptable details of all the requests made by `script.sh`?

Comment: [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) is a GUI app but can be installed under Linux. Or you can install it on a Windows machine and direct your Linux to use it as a http proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the link but I suggest you to decrypt the encrypted traffic like [here](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/decrypting-ssl-tls-traffic-with-wireshark/)

Comment: I don't necessarily need to decrypt the traffic. Being able to see intercept-able details (hostname connected to, maybe size of the encrypted traffic) would be enough. Though I want it to be a command line utility rather than GUI util like wireshark.

Comment: for sniff traffic from command line you can use *tcpdump* or *tshark* (this is the cli version of wireshark). But there are many other different types of sniffer. Now I'm not on linux but u can search on google. For tcpdump a basic line could be *tcpdump -i interface -nn -s0 -w filetolog.log*